# Google sheets recursive ROUND for fractional parts

Tags: google-sheets

I have a number with fractional parts, but Google sheets ROUND function works only for first number specified in places parameter:

1. 1.48852 => ROUND(1.48852) => 1
2. 1.48852 => ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(1.48852,5),4),3),2),1),0) => 2

Is any function in Google sheets that would work as shown in the second case?
Basically, I want something like ROUND but work recursively.

Comment: How many of these numbers do you haven your spreadsheet? Is there any consistency with the number of decimal places that the numbers get? I can imagine creating a custom function, but this might not be very efficient if you have a lot of numbers.

Comment: Actually, I have only a few places, where this function is actually needed. So I put this 2nd variant there. I don't have there some consistency, but in most cases, it was ~5 numbers after the dot.  This question goes more from my curiosity than need. Seems I didn't miss any standard functions that could work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no, I don't believe that there is any function that enables recursive rounding (or recursive anything for that matter).

However, with the same degree of curiosity that you showed in asking this question, I've looked at how I might achieve a recursive result through scripting. This is the result.

```
function reround(input) {
  var num1 = 5;
  do {
    input = input.toFixed(num1); 
    input=+input;
    num1--;
  }while (num1 >-1); // continue running the loop while is greater than -1, i.e. until num1 = 0
 return input;

}
```

This code gets entered as a script and then the function is available for use in the spreadsheet. It only takes one parameter (value) because the number of places is coded into the script. But no doubt, one could modify the code to accept the number of decimal places as a parameter also (I wasn't *that* curious;).

---

[image: ROUND function]

This is the sequence of values at each stage of the conventional and recursive rounding.

---

[image: REROUND Function]

This is the log of values from the REROUND process.
Interesting to note the difference at three decimal places. It's not something that I've explored, so I don't have an explanation.